# Organizing NSLayoutContraints between code and IB

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nslayoutconstraint

I'm sure that this must be a common issue. I have a UIViewController which has a UINavigation bar, and a ContentView (which contains UIView and a bunch of children controls. The user can hide this content view by swiping left, then it animates off the left side of the screen. I want the navigation bar to expand and fill the entire width. You cannot link these two with Interface Builder, so it must be done in code. No problem:

```
    // Called from viewWillAppear
    -(void)addLayoutConstraints{
        UINavigationBar *navigationBar = self.navigationBar;
        UIView *facetView = self.facetViewController.view;
        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(navigationBar, facetView);
        NSArray* constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[facetView]-[navigationBar]-|"
                                                                                options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline
                                                                                metrics:nil
                                                                                  views:views];
        [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    }
```

That code snipped should do it just fine. The problem is that I have laid out the UINavigationBar in IB, so that I can easily add customized buttons to it and see it, etc... The issue is that when I layed out the navigation bar in IB, IB adds a bunch of default constraints that cannot be removed. One of which is in conflict with the one I added in the code above.

How do you get around this? Here are 3 possibilities I came up with:

1.) I could create the UINavigation bar programmatically as well. This way it only has the constraints that I add to it. I'd prefer not do it this way, but it's an option

2.) Using IB, somehow delete the default constraints so that they don't' collide. I do not see a way to do this

3.) In code, remove the default constraints that IB adds to the UINavigation bar, then add my custom constraints. I do see that there is removeConstraint and removeConstraints. I suppose I could retrieve the constraints, remove them, then add my own. Again, kinda long messy process.

What is your opinion? Have you done similar?

Comment: Option 3 is the way to go. You can make IBOutlets to any of the constraints that IB creates for you, and then either delete them or modify the constant value.

Comment: How do you do that exactly? I did seomthing like NSArray* constraints = navBar.constraints; [self.view removeConstraints:constraints]; That seemed to remove some of them. I'm curious about what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: You make IBOutlets, and connect them to the constraints in IB, just like you would with any other IBOutlet (sometimes you can click on the UI element so you can see the constraints, and connect them there, or you can connect to the list of constraints in the scene list on the left of the screen). Then in code you remove them using the name of the outlet.

Comment: Well I'll be....... Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Option 3 is the supposed way. It is exactly talked about in this WWDC 2012 session — [Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.16351493766).

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged (links tend to get stale over time).
Please consider editing your answer and adding a synopsis here.

Comment: It is not a link-only answer. I answered the question in the first sentence. The second sentence contains the link to the *video* that supports my answer.

Comment: Agreed, it's a bit borderline :-) Well, there are reasons to choose option 3, no? For a good answer I would expect you to at least summarize them.